# body height 100% displaying horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

When I give height 100% to body tag its display horizontal scroll. I don't know where it comes from but when I set body height to 100% it displays a horizontal scroll.

Comment: don't forget to include your minimum code snippet to post question.

Comment: No need to get rude. The question should include a code snippet that shows your problem. That is practice on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `overflow-x: hidden;` 
I reccoman you learn about `overflow`:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Its generating horizontal scroll not vertical.

Comment: tell if it helped

Comment: I set  `overflow-y` because you tell us about `height`

Comment: this make a new vertical scroll bar which looks horrible

Comment: height 100% displaying horizontal scroll

Comment: try this:`overflow:hidden`

Comment: @FawadAli I don't agree with the solution, you should show us your code, the overflow will hide the scroll (so you will hide the issue) but we need to see WHY you have the scroll bar to avoid it not to hide it

Comment: @TemaniAfif maybe you right but I tried to help him without minimal code ... but he use `overflow-x:hidden`

Comment: overflow/overlow-x or overflow-y are the same --> they will hide the scroll and we still don't know why we have the scroll. I don't say you are wrong I added his name to notify him that it's better to add his code so we can see the real issue.

Comment: @TemaniAfif right...by the way you have awosome answers I like to follow you :)

Comment: sorry to all of you next time I will include the code.

Comment: @Temani overflow hides all of the scrolls in the web page if you give it to body overflow:hidden: and I just want to disable the horizontal scroll. So overflow-x: hidden; works for me.

Comment: All of you do a great job and here I am to learn from you people so next time I will include the code. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @FawadAli we all know what overflow do :) but my concern is better include your code so we can see and give you solution not trying to guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-x: hidden;`

But this will hide scrollbar even if the data on the page is more than the height of the page.

If that is the case, you may use `overflow-x: auto;` which will hide/show the scrollbar based on content on the page.

Comment: Its not working for me and please read the question carefully. The problem is its generating horizontal scroll not vertical

Comment: i haven't seen property called `overflow-h` through out my career :)

Comment: its overflow-x not overflow-h